# How to set the heap size for GraalVM native image?

Tags: graalvm

How can I control the heap size of a native image created with GraalVM `native-image`?

Does the native image evaluate the usual JVM `-Xmx` argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the heap size with `-Xmx{n}` command line parameter. For instance,

```sh
./your-native-binary -Xmx16m
```

will set 16m heap size for Substrate VM. You can also add `-XX:+PrintGC` flag to check garbage collector activity:

```sh
./your-native-binary -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xmx16m
```

Comment: But my program itself reads command-line argument. Adding `-Xmx16m` won't make the program work.

Comment: Just tested that this argument is removed in the `args` array of the program.